# Obtener resultado de requestPermissions al solicitar permisos

Tags: android, android-permissions

Necesito leer y escribir archivos de una ruta especifica en mi SDcard, cuando trabajo con versiones de Android que no requiere que se otorguen permisos no tengo problemas, pero cuando trabajo con versiones que requieren permisos estoy escribiendo lo siguiente:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // mis rutinas
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PrincipalActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);
            return;
        }
    }else{
        // mis rutinas;
    }
```

quiero saber si es posible obtener el resultado luego de aceptar o no el permiso solicitado con ***ActivityCompat.requestPermissions***, para así poder lanzar una rutina que requiera este resultado.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguí lo que necesitaba con lo siguiente:

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
...
...
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // mis rutinas
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PrincipalActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
}else{
    // mis rutinas;
}
```

y luego para validar si se aceptó o no los permisos utilizo el método ***onRequestPermissionsResult***, quedando así:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                // Permission Granted
                // Rutina que se ejecuta al aceptar
            }else{
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(PrincipalActivity.this, "No se aceptó permisos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Has probado después de requerir los permisos, revisar si estos fueron aceptados?

```
...
...
...
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PrincipalActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);        

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permiso Aceptado.
    }else{
       // Permiso NO aceptado.
    }
...
...
...
```

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, lo resolví de otra manera siguiendo el mismo esquema que tenia trabajando, pero utilice el método onRequestPermissionsResult, ahora publico la respuesta.